# What parameters is golang crc32 using?

Tags: go, checksum, crc, crc32

I have a crc32 polynomial:

```
poly=0xF4ACFB13
seed=0
xorout=0
refin=no
refout=no
check=0x6c9f84a8
```

I cannot get golang builtin crc32 package to give me the correct checksums.

This website https://www.lddgo.net/en/encrypt/crc yields the correct sums.
(sum for string "0" should be 0xC45441EB)

This website https://simplycalc.com/crc32-text.php yields the same as go (if I reverse poly).
(sum for string "0" shows 0x1D62A0AB instead same as go)

Can someone help me understand why a function with such basic parameters isn't matching?

Comment: Can you tell me how you got `0xC45441EB` on the site you linked? Entering `0`, choosing CRC32, the result is `0xF4DBDF21`, same as given by Go.

Comment: To obtain `0xC45441EB` as the result, you have to set the algorithm to `Custom` and populate the parameters as specified in the question. When the bit width is set to 32, all the hex fields have to be 8ndigits long (e.g. `00000000` for seed and xorout). The refin and refout options need to be unchecked.

Comment: One thing that would have helped a little is if the check is non-zero, then xorout is also non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

Using https://www.lddgo.net/en/encrypt/crc, the following parameters produce a result which matches the Go `hash/crc32` implementation and the Javascript implementation at https://simplycalc.com/crc32-source.php:

- Bit Width: `32`
- Polynomial Formula (HEX): `F4ACFB13`
- Initial Value (HEX): `FFFFFFFF`
- XOROUT (HEX): `FFFFFFFF`
- REFIN: true
- REFOUT: true

This answers the initial question, "what parameters are being used?"

If you're open to considering an alternative implementation, you might use one that's designed to be more flexible. See https://github.com/snksoft/crc.

Note that With `hash/crc32`, you can use an alternative initial value via the first argument of [`func Update(crc uint32, tab *Table, p []byte) uint32`](https://pkg.go.dev/hash/crc32#Update). Otherwise, the parameters are hardcoded. Note that these hardcoded parameters are shared between the predefined polynomials (i.e. IEEE, Castagnoli, and Koopman). Adding support for more parameters to `hash/crc32` doesn't look straightforward, as it would require modifying the binary marshaling/unmarshaling functionality, which is subject to the backwards compatibility guarantee (see the last paragraph in https://pkg.go.dev/hash#Hash).

---

Here's an example comparing usage of `hash/crc32` and `github.com/snksoft/crc`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "hash/crc32"
    "math/bits"

    "github.com/snksoft/crc"
)

func crcSnksoft(params *crc.Parameters, input []byte) uint32 {
    h := crc.NewHash(params)
    h.Update(input)
    return h.CRC32()
}

func crcGo(poly uint32, input []byte) uint32 {
    reversedPoly := bits.Reverse32(poly)
    t := crc32.MakeTable(reversedPoly)
    return crc32.Checksum(input, t)
}

func main() {
    poly := 0xF4ACFB13
    data := []byte("0")

    params := &crc.Parameters{
        Width:      32,
        Polynomial: uint64(poly),
        Init:       0x00000000,
        ReflectIn:  false,
        ReflectOut: false,
        FinalXor:   0x00000000,
    }

    mimicGoParams := &crc.Parameters{
        Width:      32,
        Polynomial: uint64(poly),
        Init:       0xFFFFFFFF,
        ReflectIn:  true,
        ReflectOut: true,
        FinalXor:   0xFFFFFFFF,
    }

    fmt.Printf("snksoft/crc: 0x%X\n", crcSnksoft(params, data))
    fmt.Printf("snksoft/crc (matching hash/crc32): 0x%X\n", crcSnksoft(mimicGoParams, data))
    fmt.Printf("Go standard library (hash/crc32): 0x%X\n", crcGo(uint32(poly), data))
}
```

Output:

```
snksoft/crc: 0xC45441EB
snksoft/crc (matching hash/crc32): 0x1D62A0AB
Go standard library (hash/crc32): 0x1D62A0AB
```

[Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/RrRKqD80ohV)

Comment: Perfect answer thank you. I did pretty much figured this to be the case after a few hours of experimentation. But I wanted to post the question to save anyone else the time. Also it makes sense for the built-in package to focus on optimizing the 99% case. But there's 4 common settings, just tell us which you used! We shouldn't need to determine them experimentally or become a CRC expert to infer them from the package. Any newcomer would expect the defaults to be {0s and falses} and not the other way around. Appreciate your recommendation I'll check out snksoft.